# Using C# to pull specific data from a SQL table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on a project where I'm required to pull specific data from a table in SQL. I'm fairly new to SQL and so all the examples given aren't helping my project process.

I'm trying to pull only the rows that have four particular values in them but I'm not sure how to do that while in C#. Do I have to run one long query or can I run multiple and C# will have what it needs to pull what I need for the project?

Here's where I'm at so far.

```
public static List<string> GetSmoothieFlavors()
{
    List<string> flavors = new List<string>();
    SqlCommand getFlavorsQuery = new SqlCommand("select * from smoothieFlavors", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = getFlavorsQuery.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            flavors.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
        conn.Close();
        return flavors;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new POSException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not modify the SQL to only return the four particular values: `SELECT * FROM smoothieFlavors WHERE SomeVal IN ('blueberry', 'strawberry', 'cheesecurds', 'bacon')`

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do it would be use `where` clause in your query in this way

```
SqlCommand getFlavorsQuery = new SqlCommand("select * from smoothieFlavors where column1 = value1 and column2 = value2", conn)
```